# How remove the numbers and cross on Elscreen tab?

Tags: elscreen

I use [Elscreen, a sort of screen ulitily manager](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsLispScreen).

It's like tabs like you have in Chrome. I use when I have too many buffers/windows to handle it, and when I run 2 different projects next to each other. I know there are other alternatives, but for now it suits me.

There is ony thingy that drives these fanatical tinker crazy. I can't change the way how the tabs looks. I added a screenshot:

[image: Elscreen]

As you can see, you see `[X] #` which # stands for number. I would like to remove the `[X] #` by default in all Elscreen tabs. When I took a dive in the [source code of Elscreen](https://github.com/shosti/elscreen/blob/master/elscreen.el), I couldn't find where he defines the numbers, so that I could disable it in my Emacs init setup.

I ever thought Lisp was easy, but I can't really find any numbers and cross defined to disable it.

Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: It's hardcoded: https://github.com/shosti/elscreen/blob/master/elscreen.el#L1478

Comment: Asides from that, you'll want to work with https://github.com/knu/elscreen

Comment: Wasamasa, I found that already and I removed the content of that (the `[X]`), but the `[X]` is still showing it up. I never found the `.elc` version of that. But isn't Emacs about extenisibility/customization. So I'm wondering if there is a way to modify it, without touching the contents of the package?

Comment: Well, if the package wasn't written with the intent to customize that specifically in mind, it's going to be a lot more work.